# Scala weird feature with foreach. expected behavior or not?

Tags: scala

```
    def list = List(1,2,3,4).map(1+_).reverse.foreach((i:Int)=> println(i))
```

compiles correctly but doesn't print anything to the screen. This was a typo on my part, but I'm suprised it compiled at all.

```
    def list = List(1,2,3,4).map(1+_).reverse.foreach((i:Int)=> println(i))
    println("--")
    list
```

shows the output as

```
   --
   5
   4
   3
   2
```

So list has become a function in this case? That's what I deduce by the output it's not what I expected

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, we have here a prime example why you should consider writing down types even though they can be inferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `list` is effectively a method that takes no parameters. The key difference to note between this definition and simply making it a `val` is that it will be evaluated every time it is used, so every time you reference `list`, the output will be printed.

As pointed out in the comment below, naming it `list` may be misleading, as `foreach` has return type `Unit`. That would have been the case regardless of how you declared `list`, though.

Comment: No, `list` is not a function, it's a method. That method returns `Unit` (more or less `void` in Java), because that is the return type of the last expression of its body.

Comment: You're right, I was sloppy in my choice of notation, and thinking of the differentiation in terms of general OO terminology that doesn't quite apply here.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you can always explicitly write type for the value and see compiler complaining about type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

A method definition doesn't execute the method. You have to call the method, too.